# Using Arduino based OpenCR with USB Host Shield 2.0 to connect to PS4 controller

Tags: usb, shields

I am trying to use a PS4 controller with my dynamixel setup using the OpenCR 1.0 board. The USB Host Shield 2.0 library is used to talk to the controller, but the current library does not support Open CR 1.0, but it does support other ARM boards. Is it easy to modify the library to talk to Open CR? My guess is that it is just the SPI pins (and other pins) that need to be redefined, but any guidance regarding the same would be great.

https://github.com/felis/USB_Host_Shield_2.0

https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/OpenCR

Comment: which library are you talking about ... questions like `Is it easy ...` are pointless ... it is easy for someone that can write a library, and not so easy for someone that can't even blink an LED

Comment: USB_Host_Shield_2.0.zip in https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/OpenCR/tree/master/arduino/opencr_arduino/libraries